# Why does this regular expression prevent entries of less than 13 but not blank entries?

Tags: objective-c, regex

If the user enters 1-12 characters the validation works but if the user enters a blank expression it doesn't work. Why?

```
 + (BOOL)validateCardNumberWithString:(NSString*)number {
        NSString *numberRegex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"^(\\d{13})?$"];
        NSPredicate *numberTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", numberRegex];
        return [numberTest evaluateWithObject:number];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `?` in the regex means that you can have 0 or 1 of the expression.  Since blank is not valid for you, it should be removed.

Also based on your description, it sounds like you want `@"^\\d{1,13}$"`, if you want to have 1-13 digits, as `\d{13}` means exactly 13 digits.

Comment: I imaging the OP is looking for something like `@"^\\d{13,}$"`, the additional comma making it mean match *at least* 13 digits ..

Comment: Actually based on the OP's description I would guess `^\\d{1,13}$`, but his question was specifically why blank was passing.

Answer (score 2):

For **less than** 13 digits, you need to use this regex instead:

```
^(\d{1,12})$
```

Here `{1,12}` is a quantifier that the match includes digits from 1 to 12 times (Non-optional).

[image: pix]